# Extracting a subset of values from an associative array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I want to do something seemingly very simple, but I can't find anything about it: simply extract a subset of an array similar to array_splice, but *using keys to retrieve the values* :

```
$data = array('personName' => 'John', 'personAge' => 99, 'personId' => 1,  
              /* many more data I don't need here ... */);

list($name, $age, $id) = array_splice_by_keys($data,
                          array('personName', 'personAge', 'personId');
```

If all else fails, isn't there a builtin function to filter an associative array by keys? For example:

**$filteredArray = array__extract__keys__and__values($srcArray, $arrayOfWantedKeys);**

```
// create a new array with ONLY those key => values I need
$wanted_values = array_extract_keys_and_values($data,
                  array('personName', 'personAge', 'personId');

echo $wanted_values['personName'];
```

I guess the reason why I want to do the first one, is that I don't like to repeat associative array access all over my code, it would seem better optimized to copy the values that are used a lot (in a loop for example), into a local variable, plus it's much easier to type $name than $somearray['name'].

EDIT: Thanks, I guess for use with list, the solution would be

```
list($x, $y, $z) = array_values(array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($wantedKeys)));
```

Intesresting use of array_flip!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in php version >= 5.1.0 you could use [`array_intersect_key`](https://secure.php.net/array_intersect_key):

```
$data = array('personName' => 'John', 'personAge' => 99, 'personId' => 1,  
          'test' => 23);
$ex = array('personName'=>0, 'personAge'=>0, 'personId'=>0);
var_dump(array_intersect_key($data, $ex));
```

values in `$ex` don't matter, they just have to be present.

Answer (score 40):

This is essentially the same as SilentGhost's answer but this might be easier, and probably a little slower.

```
array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($wantedKeys));
```